# Is it possible to activate the compatibility mode for Oracle in SQL Database?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Is there any way to activate compatibility mode for Oracle in any of the existing plans of SQL Database (DB2) in Bluemix? It seems by default is not activated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle compatibility is a database level feature and cannot be enabled if the database is created with the feature disabled.

Comment: Is it possible to create a database with the feature enabled...maybe by using the Premium plan?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below commands in db2 for oracle compatibility on database level:

In a DB2 command window, start the DB2 database manager by issuing the following command:

db2start

Set the DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR registry variable to one of the following values:

```
The hexadecimal value that enables the specific compatibility feature that you want to use.
To take advantage of all the DB2 compatibility features, ORA, as shown in the following command. This is the recommended setting.
```

db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA

Enable deferred prepare support by setting the DB2_DEFERRED_PREPARE_SEMANTICS registry variable to YES, as shown:

db2set DB2_DEFERRED_PREPARE_SEMANTICS=YES

If you set the DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR registry variable to ORA and do not set the DB2_DEFERRED_PREPARE_SEMANTICS registry variable, a default value of YES is used. However, it is recommended that you explicitly set the DB2_DEFERRED_PREPARE_SEMANTICS registry variable to YES.
Stop the database manager by issuing the db2stop command:

db2stop

Start the database manager by issuing the db2start command:

db2start

More details below:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/t0054729.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/dmmag/DMMag_2009_Issue2/InTrans/

Comment: We can't do that I think against a DB2 created from Bluemix, can we?

Comment: probably u can use sqldb aka db2 in bluemix